# Do I need to repeat all the categories on all sub-pages?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am marking up the content on my website with microdata. I am a Local Business and use this hierarchy:
Organization/LocalBusiness/TravelAgency/

Do I need to repeat all the relevant Properties for each category: PLace, Organization, Local Buisness and Travel Agency in each page of my website?

http://schema.org/TravelAgency

I have many sub-pages and it is over-kill to repeat everytime on the page the location, address, telephone, etc. of the business.

For specific sub-pages can I cut out the higher categories?

For example: If I have a page: Special Offer Weekend in New York

Do I add all the Properties or can I just add the ones relevant for TravelAgency and potentially Price?
http://schema.org/PriceSpecification

Thanks for your help

PS: I ask this because I have read that it is not good to have invisible content for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema.org doesn’t define any required properties, so everything is optional.

But note that there is no concept of "website" in Microdata. The Microdata always gets parsed per document. So if a Microdata consumer parses your "Special Offer Weekend in New York" page, it will not get the telephone/address/etc. of the business, even if these would be specified on all of your other pages.

If you don’t want to markup all the visible content about your business on every page, you might want to link to a page where this data is marked up (e.g., the front page) by using an appropriate Schema.org property.

Example: On "Special Offer Weekend in New York" ([`Offer`](http://schema.org/Offer)), you could use the [`seller` property](http://schema.org/seller) to link to your front page ([`TravelAgency`](http://schema.org/TravelAgency)).

It’s not defined in Microdata that those links should be followed for parsing Microdata, but that way parsers can (if they want to) understand that all these pages belong to the same `TravelAgency`.

Comment: Thank you Unor. That answers my question and makes sense! :-) Can you recommend any websites travel or otherwise that use microdata in a good manner?

Comment: @Julien: Sorry, I don’t know such travel sites. If you have built something, you could ask for review of your HTML5+Microdata on [codereview.se].